# How to mapping column from oledbsource to oledbdestination using SSIS in C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I want to make mapping from

```
OleDbSource (select mFK_Prefix,mFK_Sufix,mElement_Base,mBase_Value,mPeriode_Start,mPeriode_End,mSandi_Pelapor,mOrder from [dbo].[STG_AAKL])
```

to

```
OledbDestination(select FK_Prefix,FK_Sufix,Element_Base,Base_Value,Periode_Start,Periode_End,Sandi_Pelapor,Order from [dbo].[TM_AAKL])
```

How to programmatically make mapping from oledbsource to oledbdestination using ssis inc#.

for complete or my program there is at below this

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
    public void Main()
    {
        string DestinationCS = @"Data Source=.\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=DWH_LSMK;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=SSIS-Package;Auto Translate=False;";
        string SourceCS = @"Data Source=.\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=DWH_LSMK;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=SSIS-Package;Auto Translate=False;";
        GeneratePackage(SourceCS, DestinationCS); 
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    protected ConnectionManager AddOleFbConnection(Package pck, string nameConexion, string cadenaConection)
    {
        ConnectionManager Cm;
        Cm = pck.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
        Cm.ConnectionString = cadenaConection;
        Cm.Name = nameConexion;
        return (Cm);
    }
    protected virtual TaskHost AddDataFlow(Package pck,string dataFlowName)
    {
        Executable e = pck.Executables.Add("STOCK:PipelineTask");
        TaskHost thMainPipe = (TaskHost)e;
        thMainPipe.Name = dataFlowName;
        return (thMainPipe);
    }
    protected virtual IDTSComponentMetaData100 AddSourceOledbFromTable(MainPipe flujo,string nombrecomponenete,string nombretable,ConnectionManager Connection )
    {
        IDTSComponentMetaData100 ConexionAoregen = flujo.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
        ConexionAoregen.Name = nombrecomponenete;
        ConexionAoregen.ComponentClassID = "DTSAdapter.OleDbSource";
        CManagedComponentWrapper instance = ConexionAoregen.Instantiate();
        instance.ProvideComponentProperties();
        ConexionAoregen.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManager = DtsConvert.GetExtendedInterface(Connection);
        ConexionAoregen.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManagerID = Connection.ID;
        ConexionAoregen.Name = nombrecomponenete;
        instance.SetComponentProperty("AccessMode",0);
        instance.SetComponentProperty("OpenRowset", nombretable);
        try
        {
            instance.AcquireConnections(null);
            instance.ReinitializeMetaData();
            instance.ReleaseConnections();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw; 
        }
        return (ConexionAoregen);
    }
    protected virtual IDTSComponentMetaData100 AddOleDbDestinationTable(MainPipe DataFlowTask,ConnectionManager destinationconnection,IDTSComponentMetaData100 fuentedatos,string tabledestination)
    {
        IDTSComponentMetaData100 ComponentDestino = DataFlowTask.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
        ComponentDestino.ComponentClassID = "DTSAdapter.OleDbDestination";
        CManagedComponentWrapper instance = ComponentDestino.Instantiate();
        instance.ProvideComponentProperties();
        ComponentDestino.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManager = DtsConvert.GetExtendedInterface(destinationconnection);
        ComponentDestino.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManagerID = destinationconnection.Name;
        instance.SetComponentProperty("AccessMode",3);
        //instance.SetComponentProperty("FastLoadOptions","TABLOCK,CHECK_CONSTRAINTS");
        instance.SetComponentProperty("OpenRowset", tabledestination);
        IDTSPath100 union = DataFlowTask.PathCollection.New();
        union.AttachPathAndPropagateNotifications(fuentedatos.OutputCollection[0], ComponentDestino.InputCollection[0] );
        instance.AcquireConnections(null);
        instance.ReinitializeMetaData();
        instance.ReleaseConnections();

        foreach (IDTSOutputColumn100 col in fuentedatos.OutputCollection[0].OutputColumnCollection)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < ComponentDestino.InputCollection[0].ExternalMetadataColumnCollection.Count; i += 1)
            {
                string campo = ComponentDestino.InputCollection[0].ExternalMetadataColumnCollection[i].Name;




                if ((col.Name.ToUpper() == "MPERIODE_START") && (campo.ToUpper() == "PERIODE_END"))
                {
                    IDTSInputColumn100 colnueva = ComponentDestino.InputCollection[0].InputColumnCollection.New();
                    colnueva.LineageID = col.ID;
                    colnueva.ExternalMetadataColumnID = col.ID;
                    colnueva.MappedColumnID = col.ID;
                    colnueva.Name = col.Name;
                    // break;
                }
                else if ((col.Name.ToUpper() == "MPERIODE_END") && (campo.ToUpper() == "PERIODE_START"))
                {
                    IDTSInputColumn100 colnueva = ComponentDestino.InputCollection[0].InputColumnCollection.New();
                    colnueva.LineageID = col.ID;
                    colnueva.ExternalMetadataColumnID = col.ID;
                    colnueva.MappedColumnID = col.ID;
                    colnueva.Name = col.Name;
                    //break; 
                }


            }
        }
        foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 inputColumn in ComponentDestino.InputCollection[0].InputColumnCollection)
            Console.WriteLine(inputColumn.Name);
        Console.Read();

        return (ComponentDestino); 

    }
    public void GeneratePackage(string SourceConnectionString, string DestinationConnectionString)
    {
        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(SourceConnectionString);
        cn.Open();
        Package Mipk = new Package();
        Mipk.Name = "KBGK_AAKL";
        Application App = new Application();
        ConnectionManager ConnOrigen = AddOleFbConnection(Mipk, "Source", SourceConnectionString);
        ConnectionManager ConnDestina = AddOleFbConnection(Mipk, "Destination", DestinationConnectionString);
        MainPipe Df = AddDataFlow(Mipk,"KBGK AAKL").InnerObject as MainPipe ;
        IDTSComponentMetaData100 source = AddSourceOledbFromTable(Df, "Source Component", "STG_AAKL", ConnOrigen);
        AddOleDbDestinationTable(Df, ConnDestina,source,"TM_AAKL" );
        App.SaveToXml(String.Format(@"D:\\LSMK-source\\SSIS\\AutoGenerate\\Autogenerate_AAKL.dtsx", Mipk.Name), Mipk, null);



    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration

    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try using bulkcopy function... it will help you to get ridoff DFT ....